# Test Explorer > Run All : System.Exception: Failed to find the main application assembly

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

When I run a selected test, the test run correctly in Test Explorer. However, when use the `Run All` button, VS2012 throws a `System.Exception` that states

> Failed to find the main application assembly...

Is there a place that I can configure the Test Explorer to find the application assembly?

An example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What "Run All" button? Are you sure you're not hitting the Play button and trying to start running within a solution that has no executables?

Comment: @BobHorn I suppose the 'Run All' link that is at the top of the new Test Explorer.

Comment: From the reading of it, it's not clear to me how to repro. Is it possible that you can log a MS connect bug with attached solution on https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio . Additionally, please specify OS/Platform as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *divide and conquer* suggestion in finding the problem.

Place the attribute [IgnoreAttribute] over all of your tests but one. Do run all. Does the same happen? If not remove the ignore over another test and run all again. Keep doing it until failure. Is a specific test in combination failing with another? If so what is that telling you...

If failure occurs immediately or regardless of the tests choosen, check the initialize methods which have [ClassInitialize()] or [TestInitialize()] over them (if you have them) and verify that they are not causing the problem such as an intiailzation happening more than once when it should only be done once by putting a breakpoint in the methods them and seeing if they are called as expected.